# Meta-analysis: Combining pre-treatment and control groups in different study designs

Tags: meta-analysis, control-group

I'm working on a meta-analysis on a subject with scant literature. I'm analyzing changes in thyroid hormones in spaceflight, looking to see if there is a significant difference between pre- and in-flight hormone levels.

However, about half of my studies report measurements from a control group on Earth and from a group exposed to microgravity. The other half reports measurements from a group before and after exposure to microgravity (i.e. the subjects act as their own controls).

Is it kosher to treat control measurements in the first study design as equivalent to pre-exposure measurements in the latter design? Because data on this topic is fairly sparse, I'd very much like to be able to use all of these studies.

Please let me know if this question isn't clear and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: There is a lot that I don't know about the studies that you're including so I'm going to make some assumptions. Assumption: Participants in the first group of studies were not assigned randomly to microgravity vs control group. It's not clear if they were matched (case-control study), participants chose which group they were in (cohort study), etc. With the second group of studies can be considered a before-after study design (each person is their own control). You can combine the two groups but first you have to adjust for the correlation in the second group. Best to work with a statistician.